# System error 5 occurred while starting oracle service through jenkins

Tags: oracle, jenkins

I am trying to start/stop following services in Jenkins job, but getting error like `access is denied, system error 5 has occurred`.

Services are:

```
net stop OracleOraDB12Home1TNSListener ,
net start OracleOraDB12Home1TNSListener,
net stop OracleServiceORCL12C,
net start OracleServiceORCL12C,
net stop OracleVssWriterORCL12C ,
net start OracleVssWriterORCL12C,
```

Comment: Did you check it by running "cmd" as "run as administrator" credential. also you can write a batch file and run it by "run as adminstrator" credential.

Comment: This can be solved by restarting above services in physical machine using services.msc .